# HttpTrigger up in the console but failing to return a response after migrating from .NET 6 to .NET 8? It runs for an extended period

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-functions

After migrating an Azure Function from .NET 6 to .NET 8 using the dotnet-isolated worker upgrade, the function service is running without errors, as indicated by the console output. However, when attempting to execute the function, the Http Trigger is not being invoked. Instead, it runs for an extended period and eventually returns a 500 status code without any error response.

Despite removing the reference to the Startup class and creating a Program class file for Host Builder and dependency injection, the output console still refers to the Startup class.

[image: Console logs]

**Program file code :**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
        <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    </PropertyGroup>
    
    <ItemGroup>
        <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
        <PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.10.4" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.AppConfiguration.Functions.Worker" Version="7.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.17.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.21.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.2.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.22.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.2.0" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <None Update="host.json">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </None>
        <None Update="local.settings.json">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
            <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
        </None>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
    </ItemGroup>
    
</Project>
```

**Program class code : **

```
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration(builder =>
    {
        string AppConfigurationConnection = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AppConfig");
        builder.AddAzureAppConfiguration(options =>
        {
            options.Connect(new Uri(AppConfigurationConnection), new DefaultAzureCredential())
            .ConfigureKeyVault(kv =>
            {
                kv.SetCredential(new DefaultAzureCredential());
            })
            .Select("*")
            .ConfigureRefresh(refresh =>
            {
                refresh.Register("Control", refreshAll: true)
                .SetCacheExpiration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30));
            });
        });
    })
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        // If using Kestrel:
        services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
        });

        // If using IIS:
        services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
        });

        services.AddAzureAppConfiguration();
        services.AddOptions<AzureAppConfigSettings>()
                        .Configure<IConfiguration>((settings, configuration) =>
                        {
                            configuration.GetSection("value").Bind(settings);
                        });
        services.AddHttpClient();
        services.AddSingleton<CommonService>();

    })
    .Build();

await host.RunAsync();
```

**Postman Error:**

```
Error: read ECONNRESET
Request Headers
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.37.0
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: 80bafe6e-83f3-4d92-9013-ece684c7c610
Host: localhost:7071
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
```

[image: Postman Error]

Comment: Mahata, Can you share your function code which you have tried?

Comment: public class Function
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function> _logger;

        public Function(ILogger<Function> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Function("Function")]
        public IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            return new OkObjectResult("Welcome to Azure Functions!");
        }
    }

Comment: Can you give the code in question instead of comment.

Comment: your main issue is after migrating the function didn't gave response in postman right?

Comment: Yes and also not hitting the function on local debugging

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved by reordering the worker NuGet packages. The function now works as expected and returns responses in Postman.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
        <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
        <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <ImplicitUsings>enabled</ImplicitUsings>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.20.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.2.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.16.4" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.21.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.AppConfiguration.Functions.Worker" Version="7.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.1.0" />

        <PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.10.4" />

    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <None Update="host.json">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </None>
        <None Update="local.settings.json">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
            <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
        </None>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**Postman Response**
[image: Postman Success response]